# Does \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false} work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, random, fpu

When I calculate very small numbers, I use the `fpu` package. But it seems `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}` does not work.

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}

% packages
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

% libraries for tikz
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gu}{6.67*10^(-11)}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mc}{5.0*random(10,14)}    

\end{document}
```

If execute this, an error occurs:

> Package PGF Math Error: the operation 'random' has not yet been implemented in the floating point unit :-( (in '5.0*random(10,14)').

Anything wrong?

Comment: Is this a copy-paste error, `¥Gu` and `¥Mc`?  It's probably supposed to be `\Gu` and `\Mc`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No error for me with PGF 3.1.3 and master.

Comment: Henri, thank you. Your comment is right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's due to a typo (`¥Gu` instead of `\Gu` and `¥Mc` instead of `\Mc`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik when the names are changed the same error occurs, so it should not be closed because of this.

Comment: The manual says: **Accessing the Original Math Routines for Programmers** As soon as the [fpu] library is loaded, every private math routine will be copied to a new name. The private implementations of pgfmath commands, which are of the form `\pgfmath<name>@`, will be available as `\pgfmath@basic@<name>@` as soon as the library is loaded. That might be a clue on how to use the regular (non-fpu) random function, although I did not find out yet how to call this basic function.

Comment: @Marijn Sorry, I misunderstood Henri's comment and didn't even try. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Marijn Do you have a way to reproduce this?  Because I can't, neither with 3.1.3 nor with the current master.

Comment: @HenriMenke go a few versions back :) with 3.0.1a the issue shows, still in widespread use unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! When I update PGF to version 3.13, the problem has solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has long been fixed.  Update your TeX distribution.

https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/061d5c7153bb7eece61f38ae31486de7bb939493

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}

% packages
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

% libraries for tikz
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

% has to come after \usetikzlibrary{fpu}!
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathfloat@install@unimplemented#1{%
  \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@prepareuninstallcmd\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname##1{\pgfmathfloat@notimplemented{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gu}{6.67*10^(-11)}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Mc}{5.0*random(10,14)}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved by PGF update to latest version.